# How can I expand a list to take care of elements such as '38359*0', which I want to represent as 38359 elements equal to 0?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

How can I expand a list to take care of elements such as '38359*0', which I want to represent as 38359 elements equal to 0?

When I encounter an element with this * operator (e.g. x*y), I would like to insert x new elements of value y.

I am loading text files with these values coming in as strings; I want to convert the list to floats in order to do math on them, but cannot figure out how to expand the list to take care of these condensed values.

Ultimately, I'd like to convert this list into a 3d array. For now, the list looks like this: '38359*0', '0.121', 0.129', '487*0', etc.

This is the code I have so far.

```py
counter = 0
for z in range(0,k):
    for y in range (0,j):
        for x in range (0,i): 
            poros_np[x,y,z] = poros[counter]
            counter += 1
```

However, I get an error on the values with the * operator.

'ValueError: could not convert string to float: '38359*0.000000''

Comment: can you create a dataframe sample? for better understanding and expected output

Comment: Ultimately, I'd like to convert this list into a 3d array. For now, the list looks like this: '38359*0', '0.121', 0.129', '487*0', etc.

Comment: can you post this to te question also how do you want the output to look like

Comment: I just edited it, thanks!

Comment: it still doesnt have the expected result. please add that too. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to iterate the list of strings and select to transform only the strings that have * in it. Then, you add as many repetitions of the number needed to a temporal list, finally you add this elements to the output list by using expand.

```
def transform(string, lst):
    repetitions, number  = string.split('*')
    tmp_lst = []
    for i in range(int(repetitions)):
        tmp_lst.append(float(number))
    lst.extend(tmp_lst)

string_list = ['38359*0', '0.121', '0.129', '487*0']
out_list = []
for s in string_list:
    if '*' in s:
        transform(s, out_list)
    else:
        out_list.append(float(s))

print(out_list)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!